# VB.Net FileSystem.Rename on non-Windows platforms

Tags: linux, vb.net, macos

When using the `FileSystem.Rename` function in VB.Net Core, warning [CA1416](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1416) pops up, saying this function is only supported on Windows. However, none of my research has gleaned what alternative there is for other OSes.

I was wondering what a workaround that works on all platforms might look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using VB6 holdovers like that in the first place, whether on Windows or not, .NET Core or .NET Framework. Pretty much any function that is a member of a module in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace should be avoided unless it provides specific value over the alternative(s).

At the very least, if you're going to use something VB-specific then use `My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile`. Even that may be Windows-specific though, because I think that it uses the Windows shell.

If you stick to straight-up, standard .NET stuff then you'd be using the `System.IO` namespace and, in this case, `File.Move`.

Comment: The reason I used rename is due to not knowing its alternatives. I'm renaming a directory dynamically, and `My.Computer` seems to be a namespace that is entirely absent from my VS installation. I was unaware of `File.Move` though. This is indeed the solution. Thank you. :)

Comment: @ReciterofPoetry, I believe that `My` is available in .NET 5 but not in .NET Core 3.1 or earlier. It may also only be available in WinForms and WPF projects in .NET 5. `System.IO` is where you should be looking for all that file system stuff though.